# emulator displays alert that program has stopped unexpectedly and force closes

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;

public class graphics extends Activity {
    AnimationDrawable logoAnimation;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView logoImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        logoImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_animation);
        logoAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) logoImage.getBackground();
    }

    public boolean  onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            logoAnimation.start();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

at first i i had a (R.id.iv1) error couldn't resolve (id) so i used quick fix ,and it gave me another file that resolved it app/res/value/id  dont know if that caused this problem
when i run it the emulator alerts me that the program stopped running enexpectidly . I ran debug d and this is where it left me . also . new to this. can someone plz point me where to look and possible answer ty.

```
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
value debug = android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/logo_animation.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020001
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One basic misunderstanding prevents you from finding your error and us helping you: You may have looked in the LogCat, but you missed the stacktrace. Filter your LogCat view with pressing the Button labeled `E` (for `Error`). More detailed information: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html If you have found your error, you might find a solution or you can post the stacktrace here and we can help you.

Comment: You need to post the actual stack trace.

Comment: Could you rephrase your last sentence in the post? I don't understand what you did/had to do.

Comment: srry not sure wich one your reffering to put 3 up keep editing srry again i placed droidnova=log utility  in my program and that is where it stopped at -then ran the d instead of e in filterand got

Comment: resourcee Resources$NotFoundException  (id=830058668824) 
 cause XmlPullParserException  (id=830058667624) 
 detailMessage "File res/drawable/logo_animation.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020001" (id=830058669384) 
  count 74 
  hashCode 0 
  offset 0 
  value  (id=830058669144) 
 stackState  (id=830058669416) 
 stackTrace null

Comment: You should read what you write before posting it. Its hard to understand when the sentence mixes, words are doubled and the length of a sentence is too long.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case the problem is that you are keeping the animation file `logo_animation.xml` in the `res/drawable`. It would be better that you keep it in `res/anim`. I am not sure this will help but the error shows that your animation file can't be found from the res/drawable.

Comment: Srry to awhile to get back.The problem is resloved but i had to insert the drawable file from the source code from the book to get it to work .not sure why it wasn't reading my file i wrote. But ty for your time and your comments.Helped greatly glad you guys or here.